# Qt tr() translation with static members and namespaces

Tags: qt, static, namespaces, translation, tr

I'm working on translation our Qt GUI project.

*.ts file is generated successfully.

I filled *.ts file with translations using Qt Linguist.

But at runtime, translation with namespaces and static members does not work.

Other translations (when tr() method calls in class, that are inherited from QObject) works ok.

I have the following code (translation does not work):

**Example with namespaces:**

```
// example with namespaces
// declaration in header
namespace Error
{
  namespace RadionetworkInput
  {
    QString alreadyInUse = QT_TR_NOOP("already in use");
    char requestFailed[] = QT_TR_NOOP("request failed");
  }
}
```

Usage in cpp:

```
// usage in cpp code0
QString error0 = Error::RadionetworkInput::alreadyInUse;
QString error1 = tr(Error::RadionetworkInput::requestFailed);
```

**Example with static members:**

```
// example with static members
// declaration in header
namespace Error
{
  class RadionetworkInput
  {
    public:
    static const QString alreadyInUse;
    static const char requestFailed[];
  }
  QString Error::RadionetworkInput::alreadyInUse = QT_TR_NOOP("already in use");
  char Error::RadionetworkInput::requestFailed[] = QT_TR_NOOP("request failed");
}
```

Usage in cpp code

```
// usage in cpp code
QString error0 = Error::RadionetworkInput::alreadyInUse;
QString error1 = tr(Error::RadionetworkInput::requestFailed);
```

**Example, with working translation:**

```
class ViewNetwork : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit ViewNetwork(QString name = tr("New Radionetwork"));
};
```

Usage in code:

```
ViewNetwork::ViewNetwork(QString name)
{
  QString dummy = name;
}
```

Using `QObject::tr()` instead `QT_TR_NOOP()` macro does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your understanding how it works. With static members variables they are initialized before `main` function starts.
This means two thing:

- they are initialized before QApplication object is created and before yuo load translation files! (I'm surprised that this didn't lead to a crash)
- value is calculated only once (not updated if translation changes)!

What you should do? Just change static variable to functions:

```
// example with namespaces
// declaration in header
namespace Error
{
  namespace RadionetworkInput
  {
    QString alreadyInUse() { return QT_TR_NOOP("already in use"); }
    QString requestFailed() { return QT_TR_NOOP("request failed"); }
  }
}
```

and

```
// example with static members
// declaration in header
namespace Error
{
  class RadionetworkInput
  {
    public:
    static QString alreadyInUse();
    static QString requestFailed();
  }

  QString Error::RadionetworkInput::alreadyInUse() { return QT_TR_NOOP("already in use"); }
  QString Error::RadionetworkInput::requestFailed() { return QT_TR_NOOP("request failed"); }
}
```

Returning translation as char[] is pointless, co I've corrected that also (I don't know why you did it).